# Clean old git branches/commits

Tags: git, version-control

I have a large repo (~100 GB) with lots of old branches that needs to be cleaned up to free repository space.

Basically, what I want to do is

1. Remove all merged branches
2. Remove all branches that were created before 2022
3. On the remaining branches, remove all commits except the last (depth of 1)

So, my current plan is this:

1. To remove merged branches from remote:

```
git branch -r --merged | egrep -v "(^\*|master|develop)" | sed 's/origin\///' | xargs -n 1 git push origin --delete
```

2. To remove branches created before 2022:

```
for k in $(git branch -r | sed /\*/d); do 
  if [ -n "$(git log -1 --before='Jan 1, 2022' -s $k)" ]; then
    git push origin --delete "${k/origin\//}"
  fi
done
```

3. Re-clone to match remote
4. To remove all commits except latest on remaining branches

```
for ref in $(git branch -r | sed /\*/d)
do
   git checkout $ref
   echo "Current branch: $ref"
   c="$(git rev-parse HEAD)"
   echo "Recreating $ref branch with initial commit $c ..."
   git checkout --orphan new-start $c 
   git commit -C $c
   git rebase --onto new-start $c $ref
   git branch -d new-start
   git reflog expire --expire=now --all; git gc --prune=now
done
```

So my question is for those with lots of git expertise, how does this plan look? Trying to get another set of eyes on it before I mess something up haha

Comment: Removing merged branches won't save any space.

Comment: Why don't you just create a backup of the repository, execute your plan and see for the results?

Comment: #3 implies you don't care about the history of the repo. If that's true why not just create a new repo with 1 commit of the state you want?

Comment: #3 also says you want the single latest commit from *multiple* branches, which won't make sense unless they all branched off of the same commit on the `master` or (`develop`). You could first merge `develop` into every other branch to get them all up to date, and then you could create a brand new repo starting with the current state of `develop`. From there, for every other branch, add the state on top of that commit to get a second commit on every other branch. But this seems like a lot of work, and it's not clear by how much it would reduce the size of the repo.

Comment: Have you calculated the size of the repo with and without history? You could try a shallow clone to get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

In general, mkreiger1's answer is something you should try.
But, I can give you general tips on how to manage this repo in the future, as well as future repos, it will save you a lot of headaches.

1. In GitHub and Bitbucket you can click a box during a pull request that says "delete source branch after merge", or something to that effect. That should be a standard action to take.
2. Can't you just do this manually through some sort of interface? You should do this if you are unsure what that command actually does. Or test the command on a different repo, I'll admit I had not seen something like that.
3. Rebasing is your friend here: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase. You would usually pick the chronologically first commit, and squash the others into it. If you do this whenever you are "done" with a specific branch, each branch will only have one commit with all the changes. I don't see why you can't still do this, one should be able to rebase a branch at any time.